# How to write a token sale that supports usdc and eth as acceptable payment method

Tags: contract-development, remix, tokens

I've built a token sale contract for my new token but i can't figure out how to implement usdc as an acceptable exchange coin for my token

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this:

```
    function sale(bool isUSDC, uint amount) external {
    if(isUSDC) {

        IERC20(USDCaddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        uint tokenAmount = calculatePricePerUSD(amount);
        IERC20(token).safeTransfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);

    } else {

        require(msg.value == amount, "Received funds not sufficient");

        uint tokenAmount = calculatePricePerETH(amount);
        IERC20(token).safeTransfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);

    }
}
```